# Best method to dynamically list available translation files located within the JAR

Tags: java, gradle, localization, internationalization

I am the new maintainer of an open source Java application that was "abandoned". Initially the app was only bundle for Windows users, I am trying to make an OSX port but I run into problem

There is a folder containing the translation (properties) files.
At first launch, the app list all property files in the resource folder and makes a list out of it. Then the user can choose the app language out of that list.

Until now the application was only supported for Windows and it was working well because the resource folder was not bundled within the Jar. 
The OSx app bundle all the resource folder within the application jar and the existing code is not working. I cant find a way to scan the resource folder located within the jar.

I am wondering if someone can help me find a fix or orient me to another approach:

1. maybe save the list of available language at build time in a dedicated file. I guess it can be automatized via Gradle.
2. hardcode the list of available language (not really clean and subject to crash if I forgot to update the list when properties files get added or removed)
3. find a way to restore the scan or folder bundled within the jar

I am using Gradle as build system

Answer (score 1):

I finally went for option 1, I execute the task below to list available languages in a configuration file. 
Then my java code simply read the configuration file when executed.

```
task createLanguageFileList()  {

    def lTranslationFiles = []
    fileTree(dir: "${projectDir}\\src\\main\\resources\\translations", include: '**/*.properties').visit {
        FileVisitDetails details -> lTranslationFiles << details.file.name
    }

    doLast {
            lTranslationFiles = lTranslationFiles.collect { it.take(it.lastIndexOf('.'))}
            println lTranslationFiles
            File lstFile = new File("${projectDir}\\src\\main\\resources\\translations\\ListLanguages.txt")
            lstFile.withWriter{ out -> lTranslationFiles.each {out.println it}
           }
}
```